# What is the largest value of $c$ such that $3^n > cn^3$ holds?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, induction

I'm just doing some extra problems for my number theory course, and as an extension to the usual "show that $3^n > n^3$ (which is an easy induction using a ratio)" the question is posed:

What is the largest value of $c$ such that $3^n > cn^3$ holds? ($n>3$)

I'm actually not sure where to go with this. Playing around with a graph and variable $c$ I think $c=1$ is it, but I've no clue how to prove this.

Thanks

Comment: Is $n$ restricted to the integers, or can it be a real number arbitrarily close to $3$? As in, are you looking for the largest $c$ such that $3^n > cn^3$ for all integers $n\geq 4$?

Comment: The wording of the question is ambiguous but I'd assume it asks for the largest integer $c$, and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ also.

Comment: Note that $3^n/n^3$ is an increasing sequence!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming - since you mention number theory - that $n\in \Bbb N$, and taking $c$ as a real (ratio) as hinted, we have $n>3$, so $n\ge 4$. You will already have proven that ratio $\frac{3^n}{n^3}$ increases with increasing $n$, so the tightest constraint on $c$ is for the lowest value of $n$.

Thus for the smallest possible $n=4,$ we require $81>64c\ $ and so $c<\frac{81}{64}=1.265625$

Answer (score 0):

Hint to solve the following inequality for $n$ (any complex number):

$$3^n>cn^3$$

Assuming $m=cn^3$, we have:

$$3^n>m$$

Thus,

$$\exp(n\log3)=m$$
$$1=m\exp(-n\log3)$$

Multiplying both side by $-\log3$ yields:

$$-\log(3)=-(m\log3)\exp(-n\log3)$$

Substituting $m=cn^3$, results in:

$$-\log(3)=-(cn^3\log3)\exp(-n\log3)$$

From here, you should be able to get this:

$$n>-3\frac{W_{-1}(-\frac{\log3}{3c^{1/3}})}{\log3} ,  n<-3\frac{W(-\frac{\log3}{3c^{1/3}})}{\log3}$$

where $W$ is the [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Haven't come across the Lambert-W function before but thanks!